# Schema.org for credit card

Tags: schema.org

I have a [website](http://creditcardhiway.com/) that gives information about credit cards. **I want to know if there is any schema for credit cards information?** e.g. for each credit card I have a [page](http://creditcardhiway.com/old-navy-credit-card) with a lot of information and I think that there is a way to implement some schema tags.

I searched a little bit on `schema.org` but couldn't find anything there. Someone please guide me in this regard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Schema.org does have the [`CreditCard`](http://schema.org/CreditCard) type, this is probably not what you need, as it’s an [`Enumeration`](http://schema.org/Enumeration) (i.e., a list of URIs) of payment methods ([`PaymentMethod`](http://schema.org/PaymentMethod)). You’d typically not use this type directly ([see an example how to use it](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/85554/17633)).

For representing the card, you could use the [`Product`](http://schema.org/Product) type. For representing the issuer, you could use the [`Corporation`](http://schema.org/Corporation) type (and [`Brand`](http://schema.org/Brand) might also be of use). For representing services offered by the card/organization, you could use the [`Service`](http://schema.org/Service) type.

And if you review these, there’s the [`Review`](http://schema.org/Review) type; for rating it, there’s [`Rating`](http://schema.org/Rating); and for an "average rating based on multiple ratings or reviews", there’s [`AggregateRating`](http://schema.org/AggregateRating).

Comment: unor thanks for your help! I can't tag it as "product" because there isn't any "price".

Comment: @TheCreditCardGuru: You don’t have to have a price for a `Product`; in fact, you can’t even have a price (there is no `price` property for `Product`). If a `Product` gets offered (e.g., for a price), you would use: `Product` [`offers`](http://schema.org/offers) [`Offer`](http://schema.org/Offer), and the `Offer` specifies the price.

Comment: Got you! I will try to implent it. Tnx for your help again :)

Comment: @TheCreditCardGuru: It seems that the `CreditCard` type got an update. It’s now also a [`FinancialProduct`](http://schema.org/FinancialProduct), so using it as a type you intended to is now possible.